# Is Logrotate missing from my Cron?

Tags: cron, logs, raspberry-pi, raspbian, logrotate

I just discovered that my Raspberry Pi has been running out of memory. Checking the contents of `/var` reveals that I had rather large log files in it (`cd /var; du -h | sort -h`):

```
1.3G    ./log/journal/f64ca66647d24dd88e5251e391dbf582
1.3G    ./mail
1.4G    ./log
2.9G    .
```

I just learned about `logrotate` and that it's supposed to live in my cronjobs. However, when checking `sudo crontab -e`, I see no reference to `logrotate` or anything resembling it. My `crontab` only contains my custom commands. It's possible that I in the past have accidentally deleted it in the `-e` edit mode without knowing what it is.

Running `logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf` potentially cleared some
logs, but I'm not sure what the effect was or indeed if this is the right command to run.

Question: Should `logrotate` be visibly included in the list, when I do `sudo crontab -e` – and if so, what are the default commands there? Since my `crontab -e` only contains my custom commands, I have no idea what the system default would be.

Comment: Is the *logrotate.timer* enabled/running? Should run once per day.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes, it looks activated: `sudo systemctl status logrotate.timer`:     `Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/logrotate.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Tue 2022-07-05 04:15:11 CEST; 6h ago
    Trigger: Wed 2022-07-06 00:00:00 CEST; 12h left`

Comment: OK, now check what logrotate is actually rotating and modify it to your needs.